# Can we have several prometheus exporter on a machine?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

Is it possible to install several exporters on the same machine?

On a machine there is the standard node_exporter :
https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter

I would like to monitor other things in addition to RAM and CPU like rsyslog for example. So I wonder if is it possible to install the following in addition.
https://github.com/soundcloud/rsyslog_exporter

I am afraid of conflict.

What do you think about this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, they communicate using a different port. Node Exporter uses the 9100 port, Rsyslog seems to use the 9104 one (I'm not sure).